# How to set alarm to play my radio application on iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a radio application on my iphone and i also add the option of setting alarm to play the radio at that time. Can i do that? And also after that i can add a sleep mode...

Comment: Read this please: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Had you got any solution to do this?
I am also in need of this. If you got any solution, please post it here... Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You would use UILocalNotification to set an alarm. But, if your application is not running or in the background, the system will display an alert and play a sound file up to 30 seconds in length. If you set an action for that alert, and that action can play the radio. But the user has to choose that action. You cannot have that action automatically play when the alert is triggered.

If your app is running in the foreground, then you can code for all situation you mention in your question.